# Using angular translate with custom directive

Tags: angular-directive, angular-translate

Currently I am creating my own directive using the angular translate. As a tooltip for the image I am using some translation. When I am switching the language, the translation text stays the same, when it should change. I think, that the directive got compiled once with the current translation value, but I don't know how to get it updated any time I switch my language (some kind recompile).

Below my directive code.

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('HomeModule')

.directive("headerName", ["tabService", "imageService", "$translate", "$filter", function(tabService, imageService, $translate, $filter){
 var directive = {};
    
 directive.restrict = 'E';
    
 directive.template = '<div class="vcenter"><img ng-src="' + imageService.getImageByKey('arrowLeftSrc') + '" height="20px" tooltip-class="custom-tooltip" tooltip="' + $filter('translate')('RETURN') + '" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-popup-delay="500" class="return-arrow"/></div>' +
       '<div class="vcenter"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x"/></div>';
    
 directive.scope = {}
 
 return directive;
}]);
```

Comment: Same problem for me ...

Answer (score 0):

In short the solution is: `translate-attr-tooltip="RETURN"`.

Don't use a `$filter` in your directive template, but the angular-translate directive `translate-attr-*` (https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translate).

Here is a JSFiddle to play around - http://jsfiddle.net/ku326j6p/2/